# Firewall block my website partially on macOS

Tags: macos, meteor, firewall, macos-sierra

Firewall block web my website partially, site load header and loader but not loading all contents.

This issue happened only in few computers and site works when turning off Firewall. I get following errors in the browser console.

[image]

Also we get following error in log

```
2017-09-28 15:16:07 Deny *.*.*.* 104.24.29.7 http/tcp 51615 80  (TCP-UDP-proxy-00) HTTP-Client.Standard.1 proc_id="http-proxy" rc="595" msg_id="1AFF-0005" proxy_act="HTTP-Client.Standard.1" line="\x88\x80+\x8e\x8d\xf6" geo_dst="USA"
Traffic
```

Can you please help me to find out the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What xhr requests are being denied? Can you post the details of those requests? Also which firewall are you referring to? On the client machine? On the client network somewhere? Or next to your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely the firewall blocking your websocket requests, check out https://www.websocket.org/echo.html and see if you can access the echo service with/without SSL from the affected machines.

If you can access the service with SSL only, you will need to install an SSL certificate on your server.

Comment: Look at his network trace - the websocket connections are successful, the cancelled requests are xhr